# Careers toolbar suddenly displaying within company page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

This has been happening a lot lately and I am not sure why.
If I look at a job listing like this: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/101733/bi-engineer-quicken-loans and scroll to the bottom of this page there is a link "return to search results".  When I click on it, it takes me back to the company page with the careers toolbar embedded into it:

[image]

I can tell it's Careers because it has my invitations as well as the link **For Employers**  But this happens in a specific way, steps to reproduce:

1. Go to search companies and search for example, Quicken
2. Select the company Quicken Loans
3. When you are on the company page scroll to the section that lists the jobs
4. Select the job **BI Engineer** as an example
5. When you are on the job listing page for BI Engineer, scroll all the way down and select the link return to search results
6. Voila the bug!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report, Jon. This is fixed now.

So those `<< search results` links are ajaxified such that they replace the content area with the results of the link. That behavior doesn't work when those links go to company pages (which was added recently). It loads the whole site into the content area which makes everyone sad.

We've wanted to start removing the ajaxy bits of the navigation in Jobs as it doesn't really match with the rest of navigation on Stack Overflow, so that's what I did here. Those links will just trigger a page load.